# setSupportActionBar with custom Material theme

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm  trying to add a custom Action Bar to a custom material Android Theme.

The problem is, for the Theme to work, my MainActivity needs to extend Activity, and, the setSupportActionBar method requires the MainActivity to extend AppCompatActivity.

Here's my MainActivity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.myToolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
}
```

My ActivityMain.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/myToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/ap_main_dark"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And my Style

```
<style name="AjudarOPeixe" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar" >
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/ap_red</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/ap_main</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/ap_main_dark</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@android:color/background_light</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/background_dark</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an AppCompat Theme:

```
<style name="AjudarOPeixe" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/ap_red</item>
    <item name="navigationBarColor">@color/ap_main</item>
    <item name="statusBarColor">@color/ap_main_dark</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/background_light</item>
    <item name="textColorPrimary">@android:color/background_dark</item>
</style>
```

Then you can have MainActivity extend AppCompatActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.myToolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was afraid that using AppCompat all the Material Design would be gone, but apparently the resources are still there.